# String was not recognized when i use datetime.parseexact()

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlparameter

When ever i tries to enter date into sqlparameter it keeps on popping string was not recognized , i even tried to use `ParseExact()` but its still showing an error.

My .aspx :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtfromdate" runat="server" Width="90px" Height="20px">
</asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="calender1" runat="server" 
                      TargetControlID="txtfromdate" 
                      Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
```

aspx.cs :

```
SqlParameter[] prm = {      
    new SqlParameter("@ContractName",SqlDbType.NVarChar){Value=txtContractname.Text.Trim()},
    new SqlParameter("@FromDate",DateTime.ParseExact(txtfromdate.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy",null)),
    new SqlParameter("@ToDate",DateTime.ParseExact(txtToDate.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy",null)) ,
    new SqlParameter("@VenID",SqlDbType.Int){Value=Convert.ToInt32(ddlsupplier.SelectedValue)} ,
    new SqlParameter("@CreatedBy",SqlDbType.Int){Value=Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"])}, //chng
    new SqlParameter("@OrgID",SqlDbType.Int){Value=Convert.ToInt32(Session["orgID"])},
    new SqlParameter("@Termsnconditions",SqlDbType.NVarChar){Value=txtTermsandconditions.Text} ,
    new SqlParameter("@Module",SqlDbType.NVarChar){Value=ddlModule.SelectedValue} ,
    new SqlParameter("@Filename",SqlDbType.NVarChar){Value=ddlAttachment.SelectedValue} ,
    new SqlParameter("@Currency",SqlDbType.NVarChar){Value=ddlCurrency.SelectedItem.Text} ,
    new SqlParameter("@ContractNumber",SqlDbType.NVarChar){Value =txtContractNumber.Text.Trim()} 
   };
```

Comment: Well... which line exactly is erroring, and what **exactly** was the input value?

Comment: in parameter @from date , input string is 12/12/2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *suspect* the problem is the *culture* installed on the server; `/` in a custom `DateTime` specifier doesn't actually represent `/` - it represents the `DateSeparator`. If you actually want it to use `/`, the simplest way to do that is to explicitly specify the *invariant* culture; try simply replacing the `null` (in `ParseExact`) with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. If *that* still doesn't work, then I strongly suspect that the incoming value is not quite `12/12/2012` - it could, for example, have whitespace or unicode hidden characters in it.

Comment: No thrz no whitespace or unicode i have used trim() , , and i have used CultureInfo.InvariantCulture but its still showing the error , but when i tries to run this program in other system its working fine , please help !!!

Comment: @AkhilRJ on exactly which line, with exactly which input, with exactly what exception?

Answer (score -1):

It's due to the datrtime foremat you are using. It depends of your SQL DB. Try to print it without exact search to see the format.